# $\left \| x+y \right \|^2+\left \| x-y \right \|^2=2\left \| x \right \|^2+2\left \| y \right \|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, normed-spaces, inner-products

In a space with inner product show that $\|x+y\|^2+\| x-y\|^2=2\left \| x \right \|^2+2\left \| y \right \|^2$

after a lot of tries I ended up with : $\begin{Bmatrix}
\langle x,x\rangle +\langle -y,x\rangle=\langle x-y,x\rangle \\ 
\langle -y,-y\rangle+\langle -y,x\rangle=\langle -y,x-y\rangle\\ 
\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x+y,x\rangle\\ 
\langle y,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x+y,y\rangle
\end{Bmatrix}$

If we add them all I think we get what we want, if we consider the fact that $\langle -y,-y\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle$
is this correct?

Does this equation have a geometric meaning? I think the inner product measures the angle and the length (not sure about that) but I can't warp my head around what this exactly says.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Comment: I cant answer your question but i remember proving this for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Your argument only works if the inner product is symmetric, which is not the case for a general inner product (for example, for a vector space over $\Bbb C$, where we have $\langle y,x\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$). So $\langle y,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle$ is equal to $\langle y,x+y\rangle$, which may be different from $\langle x+y,y\rangle$. Similarly, you are assuming that $\langle -y,x-y\rangle$ is the same as $\langle x-y,y\rangle$. Better to use @PierreCarre's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write
$$
\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x+y, x+y\rangle, \quad \|x-y\|^2 = \langle x-y, x-y\rangle,
$$
and use the properties of the inner product.

---

Note that the inner product is bilinear. In this case,
$$
\|x+y\|^2=\langle x+y, x+y \rangle = \langle x,x\rangle + \langle x,y \rangle +\langle y,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 + 2 \langle x,y\rangle
$$

$$
\|x-y\|^2=\langle x-y, x-y \rangle = \langle x,x\rangle - \langle x,y \rangle -\langle y,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 - 2 \langle x,y\rangle
$$

Although I'm assuming symmetry in the last step, the main result holds regardless of that.

Comment: I couldn't do it, maybe I am not so familiar with all the properties to put them into proving that. If someone wants to write it  to help me  that would be great, if not it's ok it's not that important exercise (I think).